# Excel Formula for a task in my studies need help please

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have a task to do in my It studies Where I need to come up with the formula myself and I am completely stuck it says I need one formula only to get these answers basically at the top of the graph it says Cost per Square metre of vinyl is $12.50 then I have to make one formula to get these answers $13,$25,$38,$50,$63,$75,$88,$100,$113 and $125 this is just for the first column it has width of vinyl in metres 1 and length of vinyl in metres 1 and I am suppose to get the answer $13 for that one Please Help

The image follows:
[image]

Comment: i suggest you elaborate on your question, adding a sample excel into the mix would surely help.. the question so far can be described as cryptic and incomplete at best..

Comment: In any case, are Excel _formulae_ valid programming questions here? I can understand VBA macros but I'm unsure about simple formulae (simple in the context of not-programming-related rather than easy). I'd better go investigate meta ... never mind, meta seems to suggest that, if something as non-programming as HTML is allowed, so too should Excel formulae :-) That seems a convincing argument to me, anyway.

Comment: @HelpWithIt, it you get a graphic up of a portion of the worksheet, that'd help a great deal. Even if you can't post images as a lower-rep user, get it up _somewhere_ on the net and let us know where, then we can move it across to here.

Comment: @HelpWithIt I suspect some of the values are rounded, and that $13 is really $12.50; $38 is really $37.50, and so forth.  If that is the case, then what you are looking at is the cost of the vinyl, and the amount of vinyl would be the cost divided by 12.50.  How that relates to your problem is unclear, but maybe it will help you formulate what your professor is looking for.

Comment: attached is link to photo of portion of my worksheet HELP https://instagram.com/

Comment: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20150221182632AAq75ef  here you can see the full worksheet posted in comments

Answer (score 0):

Place the following formula in cell `c9`:

```
=C$8*$B9*$L$4
```

then extend it across the desired range, and ensure all cell formats are rounded to zero decimal places.

The use of the `$` "fixing" prefix will ensure, that on extending the formula, it will reference the correct height and width of the vinyl, as well as the correct cost per square meter.

You could also forget about cell formatting if you were to use the formula:

```
=round(C$8*$B9*$L$4,0)
```

That may be necessary if the costing rule isn't actually rouding but something like rounding *up* to the nearest dollar, in which case you could do something like:

```
=trunc(C$8*$B9*$L$4+0.99)
```

---

For example, here's the use of the `trunc` formula in a real Excel 2013 spreadsheet (albeit without your fancy formatting like borders and currency symbols):

[image]

Comment: @HelpWithIt, suggest you try harder :-) As per the attached graphic, it works just fine.

Comment: @HelpWithIt, then you have another _separate_ issue, nothing to do with the formula. Suggest you post _exactly_ what's held in one of the cells after you've input the formula. And there's no need to "shout", we can read lowercase letters just fine. And check that `L4` cell, make sure that's the one with the `12.50` in it.

Comment: @HelpWithIt, I mean, like my own graphic, show us the actual formula you've put into `C9`. On mine, you can see it in the formula box but you can just copy-paste it as text from your own spreadsheet.

Comment: I got it to work thankyou very much you have been a great help I apologize for caps was just getting frustrated

Comment: @HelpWithIt: no probs, my skin is so thick, they used to used it to line government buildings back in the cold war, in case a nuke went off nearby :-)